# Какая разница между render и return в ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Я новичок в **ReactJs** и я запутался между тем где надо использовать `render` а где `return` для монтировки JSX в DOM

1-ый синтаксис только return

```
   return <button>Hello</button>;
```

2-ой синтаксис `return` внутри `render`

```
render() {
    return (
      <button>
        Hello
      </button>
    );
  }
```

То есть по сути оба варианта делают одно и то же если я правильно понимаю но когда и где какую надо использовать ?Можно ли использовать `render` без `return`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё не так, как вы думаете. Давайте начнем с метода [`render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) - это обязательный метод, рендеринг компонента. Код данного метода должен быть чист, что означает, что он не должен изменять состояние компонента. Метод должен возвращать результат, который будет отрисован  браузером. То есть если вы ничего не вернете из него через `return` - то ничего не отобразится.

Метод `render()` является единственным обязательным методом в компоненте класса. При вызове он должен проверить `this.props` и `this.state` и вернуть один из следующих типов:

- React elements
- Arrays and fragments
- Portals
- String and numbers
- Booleans or null

То есть он обязательно должен что-то вренуть и это что-то - должно быть одним из предыдущего списка. Для изучения почитайте:

- [Rendering Elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)
- [React.Component `render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render)

Теперь перейдем к `return` - это всего лишь то, что будет возвращено из функции. В рендеринге, в возвращаемом значении принято возвращать один из описанных выше элементов, который будет отрисован браузером. В файлах JSX вы можете возвращать HTML-разметку в качестве результата и в дургих местах, то есть могут быть промежуточные функции рендеринга, возаращающие части вашего компонента.

Можно ли использовать `render` без `return`? - а какой смыл, если в таком случае ничего не отрисуется? Оператор `return` завершает выполнение текущей функции и возвращает её значение. Почитайте и это: [JavaScript `return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)